# Selenium 2 Test "_blank" Window

Tags: selenium, phpunit, selenium-rc, selenium-ide

i'm runnin a hedless selenium (PHPUnit) Test on my VM this way:

```
Xvfb :99 -ac &>/dev/null & DISPLAY=:99 java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.33.0.jar -browserSideLog -firefoxProfileTemplate "/root/.mozilla/firefox/i5a8df1g.default"
```

And it works fine. Now i try to test a form which opens a new window when it is submitted, running the Test in Selenium IDE works fine. A new Window opens and a can access to it.

```
<tr>
<td>submit</td>
<td>//form[@action='/?ac=user&amp;ac2=cb']</td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>storeEval</td>
<td>selenium.getAllWindowNames()[1];</td>
<td>windowName</td>
</tr> 
 <tr>
<td>selectWindow</td>
<td>${windowName}</td>
<td></td>
</tr>
```

when i use the getAllWindowNames() function in IDE i allway get something like "_blank123456" back in the windowName variable so i can access to it using selelctWindow(${windowName}) function

when i Export it to PHPUnit i get this code:

```
$this->submit("//form[@action='/?ac=user&ac2=cb']");
$windowName = $this->getEval("selenium.getAllWindowNames()[1];");
$this->selectWindow($windowName);
```

In PHPUnit this function allways returns "null" so it seems that there is no new window.

When i use PHPUnit function $this->getAllWindowNames(); directly i get back an array with 1 entry (name of the main window)
 i allready disabled the FF popup blocker but without any effect. When i ran the test in on the vm in a xwindow then it worked too. But runningi it headless always fails. 
Any suggestions to make it work headless?
Sincerely.
Many thanks.

Comment: Very interesting; do you have a link (or can you post here, if not too off-topic) exactly how you got headless selenium working? E.g. exactly which linux distro and which packages did you need to install from a base installation. (I'm using PhantomJS when I need headless, and also more and more with phpUnit, in preference to Selenium; though it has its own downsides.)